# Is the "distance limit" of measurable functions measurable? (Exercise 1.7 Karatzas and Shreve)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Given that $X_s$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable for $s\le t$, is $\lim_{s\to t^-} X_s\in\mathcal{F}$? I am aware of the analogous result for sequences: if $f_n\in\mathcal{F}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\lim_n f_n\in\mathcal{F}$.

An affirmative answer would complete my solution to Exercise 1.7 of *Karatzas and Shreve's Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus*.

The exercise: Let $X$ be a process for which every sample path is right continuous with left limits existing. Let $A$ be the event that $X$ is continuous on $[0,t_0)$, and show that $A\in \mathcal{F_{t_0}}^X\equiv \sigma(X_s:0\le s\le t_0)$.

My attempt: Interpret $X$ continuous on $[0,t_0)$ to mean
$\lim_{s\to t}X_s(\omega)=X_t(\omega)\ \forall\omega\in\Omega.$
Since $X$ is right continuous, it suffices to show $\lim_{s\to t^-}(\omega)=X_t(\omega)$ for all $\omega$.

For $t<t_0$, $X_t\in\mathcal{F_{t_0}}^X$. I SPECULATE that this implies $\lim_{s\to t^-}X_s\in\mathcal{F_{t_0}}^X$. (The limit of a sequence of measurable functions is measurable; is the ``distance limit'' of measurable functions measurable?)

Then $\{\lim_{s\to t} X_s=X_t\}\in\mathcal{F_{t_0}}^X$ for each $t\in[0,t_0)$, since if $f,g\in\mathcal{F}$, $f-g\in\mathcal{F}$, hence $\{f-g=0\}\in\mathcal{F}$, as $0$ is a Borel set.

Right continuity implies that $X$ continuous is on $[0,t_0)$ iff $\lim_{s\to t} X_s(\omega)=X_t(\omega)$ for all $t$ in a countable dense subset of $[0,t_0)$, i.e.
$\{X(\omega)\text{ cont on }[0,t_0)\ \forall \omega\}=\cap_{q\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,t_0)}\{\lim_{s\to q^-} X_s=X_q\}.$

Note that the RHS is a countable intersection of elements of $\mathcal{F_{t_0}}^X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By assumption, the left-limit $\lim_{s \uparrow t} X_s(\omega)$ exists for all $\omega$ and $t$. This means, in particular, that

$$\lim_{s \uparrow t} X_s(\omega) = \lim_{n \to \infty} X_{s_n}(\omega).$$

for any sequence $(s_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq (0,\infty)$ such that $s_n \uparrow t$. Choose for instance $s_n := t-1/n$, then we find that

$$\lim_{s \uparrow t} X_s(\omega) = \lim_{n \to \infty} X_{t-1/n}(\omega)$$

is $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable as pointwise limit of $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable functions.